# Creating a python scrabble function that takes a string as input and returns a score for that word

Tags: python

Hi i am working on Codecademy exercise 9/15. The goal is to create a scrabble function that takes a string as input then returns a score for that word.

They give you a dictionary to start off with and this is what I have so far after searching for "how to loop through a dictionary and add values" on google.

```
score = {"a": 1, "c": 3, "b": 3, "e": 1, "d": 2, "g": 2, 
         "f": 4, "i": 1, "h": 4, "k": 5, "j": 8, "m": 3, 
         "l": 1, "o": 1, "n": 1, "q": 10, "p": 3, "s": 1, 
         "r": 1, "u": 1, "t": 1, "w": 4, "v": 4, "y": 4, 
         "x": 8, "z": 10}




1) total = 0 # takes your input word value and saves it to total 


2) def scrabble_score(x):       # defining function name 
3)     for i in score.values(): # loops through score           
4)         total += i           # sums up your input key value
5)     return i
```

this code keeps throwing a local variable total error.

does this mean that the total variable does not work with the scrabble_score(x) function?

Comment: You also have a different problem. Note that you never use the variable `x` in your function, meaning whatever result is returned does not depend on the input word. You would also probably do better declaring `total` inside of the function, so that you can calculate a different total each time the function is called.

Comment: You're also returning `i` which means you're just returning the last score.

Answer (score 3):

You need to put `total = 0` *inside* the function, and you need to loop through the *input word*, then add each letter's score from the dictionary. You also need to return `total`, not `i`.

```
SCORES = {"a": 1, "c": 3, "b": 3, "e": 1, "d": 2, "g": 2, 
          "f": 4, "i": 1, "h": 4, "k": 5, "j": 8, "m": 3, 
          "l": 1, "o": 1, "n": 1, "q": 10, "p": 3, "s": 1, 
          "r": 1, "u": 1, "t": 1, "w": 4, "v": 4, "y": 4, 
          "x": 8, "z": 10}

def scrabble_score(word):
    total = 0
    for letter in word:
        total += SCORES[letter]
    return total
```

Here's another way to do it, to keep in mind for the future:

```
def scrabble_score(word):
    return sum(SCORES[letter] for letter in word)
```

Comment: just to clarify for "total+= SCORES[letter]

Comment: @PRamos, I don't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

You have `total += i` but there is no variable named `total` in scope at this point.  Consider initializing it with `total=0` before the loop.  Or, declare `total` as a global variable.

Also, your loop does not appear to be considering the value of `x`, so all it's going to do is calculate the total of all possible scores.

And then return an index instead of the total.

Answer (score 0):

When you use a dictionary, you don't need to loop through it. the way to access a dictionary value is very simple. For example in the dictionary you have:

```
score = {"a": 1, "c": 3, "b": 3, "e": 1, "d": 2, "g": 2, 
         "f": 4, "i": 1, "h": 4, "k": 5, "j": 8, "m": 3, 
         "l": 1, "o": 1, "n": 1, "q": 10, "p": 3, "s": 1, 
         "r": 1, "u": 1, "t": 1, "w": 4, "v": 4, "y": 4, 
         "x": 8, "z": 10}
```

if you wanted to get the value for 'a' all you would have to do is:
`score['a']` this will return the value that is set for the key 'a', you would get `1`. if you wanted to use variables you could do something like this:

```
test='b'
total=score[test]
print(total)
```

you would get:

```
3
```

all you have to do is loop through the String that you have and call each letter and add them to the total.
make sure you set the total to `0` before you start too or else you would get errors. once you are done looping through each letter in the word return the total.